# Why is this form much wider at runtime than at design time?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am creating a very small form in VS2012 which looks like this in the designer:

[image]

But when I run the app the form will increase in size and  look likes this:

[image]

Any ideas why? I tried different form border styles still the same results.

I would appreciate if you also try to see you get the same results.

I have a feeling that there is a minimum size limit for the form in VS. In this case the question is why IDE let user re-size the form under that limit.

In the linked so called duplicate answer (which is NOT working either) the person who answered says "I Tested on Windows 8.1 I can't promise that it will work on all Windows versions" And Guess what, I have windows 7 and answer DOES NOT WORK! –

Comment: This is flagged for moderation to decide if it should be re-opened, would please explain why it's not a duplicate? It certainly looks related.

Comment: And here is the big problem with SO. As OP I tried the supped answer and from still gets bigger. So this answer is NOT working for me. Simply because someone has lots of points here does not his answer are all working and you should blindly close the question.

Comment: In the linked so called duplicate answer (which is NOT working either) the person who answered say "I Tested on Windows 8.1 I can't promise that it will work on all Windows versions"
And Guess what, I have windows 7 and answer DOES NOT WORK!

Comment: You blindly closing a question or mark it as duplicate only further degrades your beloved website SO. If that't what you like, go for it. Who am I to oppose it? I even encourage you to do more like this ;)

Comment: I suggest bring your other gang buddies to down vote more. I'm really laughing. You guys Sad. Ironically Duplicate question is voted up :) haha.

Comment: Calm down, I've not voted on the question and I was asking for clarification. I don't do windows development and it certainly looked like the question was the same without further clarification.

Comment: All ok. Believe it or not but these illogical gang downvotes actually helping my purpose, so I like them. More, better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum size of the window is based on the minimum usable caption bar.  One that leaves enough room for the icon and the min/max/close buttons.  Even for windows that don't have one, bit of a bug.  Simple to workaround however, you can change the size to in the Load event.  Watch out for rescaling due to the video DPI setting.  Roughly:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        this.ClientSize = new Size(
            numericUpDown1.Right + numericUpDown1.Left,
            numericUpDown1.Bottom + numericUpDown1.Top);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: if I have Base.Onload(e) I get an exception at `this.ClientSize = new Size(
            numericUpDown1.Right + numericUpDown1.Left,
            numericUpDown1.Bottom + numericUpDown1.Top); {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}`

Comment: Did you try your solution?

Comment: If I comment out Base.Onload form remains over-sized.

Comment: Exact exception is this; `An unhandled exception of type System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll`

Comment: Yes, I tested it thoroughly.  You need to write proper VB.NET code, it is MyBase.OnLoad(e)

Comment: how did you come with `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)`

Comment: I have `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` Remember I use a Winform not a webform.

Comment: That's not what my code looks like, does it?  It was meant to be copy/paste code.  If you use the event then do **not** call base.OnLoad(). that blows since it fires the event again.

Comment: OK I copy pasted your code, no errors but still form gets re-sized(gets bigger)

Comment: @HansPassant I flagged this as a duplicate of one of my questions. (Answered by you) Please don't get me wrong, given the amount of questions you answer I don't expect you to remember them all;)

Comment: numericUpDown1 size remain constant only form gets bigger.

Comment: @Bjørn - Lord knows I'd like to close it too, that one is going to send him off the cliff completely though.

Comment: I keep the question open as the answer given here did not work(Vs2012). Also the claimed duplicate answer is not a answer this this question at all. If you know a working answer let me know. Now don't be hateful and give a good question downvotes(don't downvote me on SO my rating in SO is my life. it is so improant for me to get upvotes haha

Comment: Oh holy SH someone downvote me again :( .now be nice ;) As I said SO upvotes is my life! like oxygen

Answer (score -1):

One could also set the `MinimumSize` in the Designer to `1;1` (as opposed to the default `0;0`).

EDIT:
I've tested this in VS2010 and VS2013 on Windows 7 and with different target frameworks (in VS13, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1).
The following sample code works in all cases. I'd welcome any comments if somebody can confirm on what systems it does not work.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form frm = new Form())
        {
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

            // -> size is 80,80 with this line,
            // and wider if this line is commented out
            frm.MinimumSize = new Size(1, 1);

            frm.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            frm.Size = new Size(80, 80);
            frm.Click += (s, e2) =>  frm.Close();
            frm.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually bother to try your solution? no it does not work.

Comment: It did not really 'bother' me much, but yes, I did try it.